# Migrate MySQL LongBlob to MS SQL IMAGE using Script Only

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having to move a database from MySQL to MS SQL. One MySQL table has a LONGBLOB column that contains uploaded files. I need to migrate that data to an IMAGE column in a MS SQL table.

My restrictions are that I work for a large corporation that provides no tools and no support for doing such a migration. I have to do everything with scripts.

What can I do?

Comment: I think you need to use VARBINARY(MAX) instead of IMAGE

Comment: OK, so suppose I use VARBINARY instead. How do I do it?